# « Parler de » + un article partitif ou l'article indéfini « des » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, partitif

Je veux exprimer la notion anglaise :

> It talks about French tax evasion. *(où « it » est un documentaire)*

En la traduisant, je suis arrivé à :

> Il parle de des évasions fiscale des française.

La construction « de des » me semble maladroite et possiblement incorrecte. Est-elle strictement correcte ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On ne trouve jamais *<s>de des</s> en français.

Lorsque la préposition *de* est suivie de l'article indéfini *des*, *<s>de des</s> est contracté en *de* (qui devient *d'* lorsque l'article est suivi d'une voyelle).

> Il parle de choses incompréhensibles. *(He is talking about [some] incomprehensible things.)*
>   Il parle d'idées incompréhensibles. *(He is talking about [some] incomprehensible ideas.)*

On fait la même élision lorsque la préposition *de* est suivie d'un article partitif (*de* + *du*, *de* + *de la* ou *de* + *de l'* deviennent *de*).

> Il parle d'évasion fiscale. *(He is talking about tax evasion.)*
>   une miette de pain *(a crumb of [some] bread, i.e. a breadcrumb)*

Une manière plus simple de voir les choses est que si la préposition *de* est suivie d'un article qui commence par *de* éventuellement contracté (*des*, *de la*, *de l'*, *du*), alors on omet complètement l'article. Les autres articles restent (« d'un(e) », etc.).

Dans la phrase que tu donnes en exemple, il s'agit d'un type bien défini d'évasion fiscale : l'évasion fiscale française. On doit donc utiliser l'article défini. De plus, on n'utiliserait pas ici l'adjectif *française* mais le complément de nom *de France* ou *en France*.

> Il parle de l'évasion fiscale en France.

Comment: Pourriez-vous détailler dans votre réponse pourquoi n n'utiliserait pas ici l'adjectif *française* mais le complément de nom *de France* ou *en France* ? Prière de le faire dans votre réponse pour la lecture en une seule fois.

Answer (score 1):

*de des* ensemble n'existent pas dans la construction d'une phrase.
*French* est ici un adjectif (a écrire avec une minuscule en français), il ne s'agit pas d'un Français ou d'une Française.

> Il parle de l'évasion fiscale française.

Au pluriel on pourrait écrire

> Il parle des différents types d'évasion fiscale

Comment: Je préciserais que, si l’on veut exprimer « de des », il faut employer « de » tout court; pour « de les », employer « des ». Mais j’ai (lâchement) pas fouiller ma bibliothèque pour confirmer tout ça, alors je n’édite pas directement.

Comment: @Édouard Par recherchant « "de" pour "de les" » sur Google, j'ai trouvé [ce site](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/articles_de_du2.htm#.UjxWjmSY5qs) qui confirme ce que vous croyez.

Answer (score 1):

Je traduirais cette phrase par :

> Il traite de l'évasion fiscale française.

ou par :

> Il traite de l'évasion fiscale en France.

voire :

> Il traite de l'évasion fiscale.

puisque l'évasion fiscale n'est pas typiquement française.

Comment: J'apprécie la traduction idiomatique, mais elle était seulement un exemple afin de montrer une construction grammaticale. La signification de l'exemple n'est pas vraiment liée au coeur de la question.