# Uses of “de” and “du” after a negative

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

I've been looking around, but there have been very contrasting answers. I just wanted to make sure of this.

Let's say the sentence is:

> Elle ne va jamais manger du chocolat

Sould it be “manger **de**” or “manger **du**”?

I am a bit confused, because I was told that the preposition after “manger” should be “du”, “de la” or “des”, but after a negative it should always be “de”.

I was wondering what the correct form was?

Comment: It's a different question, but it made me think of this one: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/12540/why-is-it-au-lieu-de

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Elle ne va jamais manger **de** chocolat

is the **correct** form as it.

> Elle ne va jamais manger **du** chocolat le lundi.

is correct but not without something to give information about a special characteristic of the chocolate or where, when, how or why this chocolate is eaten. Here, saying that this only occurs on monday.

Comment: Ta seconde tournure me laisse perplexe. Je dirais que la question de généralité doit porter sur le chocolat, pas sur le reste. Soit elle ne mange pas de chocolat en général, soit elle ne mange pas de celui-ci en particulier. Ici, même en précisant que c'est le lundi, c'est une habitude et donc une vérité générale. Par conséquent, j'aurais tendance à utiliser « de ».

Comment: @Chop Tu peux effectivement remplacer le *"du"* par un *"de"* dans la deuxième phrase, cependant, si tu veux utiliser *"du"*, tu es obligé de préciser la manière, la particularité de comment est mangé ce chocolat. Ici, même si cela est général à tous les lundis, c'est une *particularité* par rapport aux autres jours de la semaine.

Comment: @YohannV. Ce qui me semble naturel pour l'utilisation de « du » est lorsqu'on pointe vers un chocolat en particulier plutôt qu'un comment/quand/où. Après, c'est peut-être aussi un sentiment lié à l'exemple (« manger »).

Comment: @Chop Je vais éditer ma réponse pour ajouter les caractéristiques du chocolat, je voulais d'ailleurs ne pas faire une liste exhaustive. L'emploi de *"du"* te semble-t-il faut?

Comment: @YohannV. J'aurais tendance à dire qu'il est accepté car couramment utilisé mais je ne suis pas ce soit juste pour autant. L'usage prévaut-il ? On peut trouver d'autres exemples. On tolère souvent « manger _du_ poisson », y compris dans des contextes de généralité. Je ne suis pas certain de pouvoir te donner une réponse absolue.

Comment: @Chop Ohlala je fais des fautes partout, *faux**.  On parle bien de la négation hein. Je ne crois pas que l'on dise : "Elle ne va jamais manger du poisson." sans compléments

Comment: Judicieuse remarque, en effet.

Comment: C'est-à-dire que "je mange de poisson", ça ne le fait pas du tout. Donc on est dans un contexte de négation.
"J'ai préparé un excellent saumon et il y a des restes de rôti. Comme elle se prend pour une sardine, elle ne va jamais manger du poisson" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7MwHGHWgLk

Comment: @MichelBillaud Je ne comprends pas bien ton commentaire. *"Comme elle se prend pour une sardine, elle ne va jamais manger du poisson"* sonne faux alors que *"Comme elle se prend pour une sardine, elle ne va jamais manger de poisson"* sonne juste.

Comment: @YohannV.  "de ce poisson que j'ai préparé". Ca se réfère à un instance concrête (pour causer informaticien), et pas au poisson en tant que substance générique.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Je ne comprends toujours pas le rapport avec la question et ma réponse. On parle de l'usage de *"du"* ou *"de"* après le verbe *manger* dans une phrase négative sans complément autre que celui du nom de la nourriture.

Comment: @YohannV  il faut effectivement un complément pour légitimer l'emploi de "du", mais c'est un complément d'information qui peut se trouver dans une autre phrase, et n'est donc pas un complément au sens de la grammaire.
D'ailleurs tu le dis "comme elle se prend pour une sardine etc sonne faux", et c'est parce la phrase est sortie de son contexte.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Du coup, je ne comprends pas où tu veux en venir par rapport à ce que j'ai écrit.

Comment: Par rapport à ta phrase "on tolère : manger du poisson". C'est pas qu'on tolère, c'est qu'on ne dit jamais "manger de poisson" dans une tournure positive. Donc on est dans les négations, et là il y a deux cas, le poisson en tant que substance générique, et le poisson animal ou plat désignés spécifiquement, par un complément de la phrase ou par son contexte.

Comment: @MichelBillaud Ce n'est pas ma phrase.

Comment: @YohannV. il semblerait en effet que, sans mes lunettes, j'aie attribué de travers ! Désolé !

Comment: @MichelBillaud Pas de soucis ;) Je ne comprenais pas ce que tu voulais me dire, sachant qu'on disait tous les deux la même chose

Answer (score 1):

Well, “je ne mange pas du gâteau” refers implicitely to some cake you could eat (like “de ce gateau”).  “Je ne mange pas de gateau” is ambiguous: you don't eat *this* cake, or you are saying you don't eat cake in a more generic way.

So, as you are expressing she *never* eats chocolate, “de” is appropriate.

But “elle n'a pas mangé du chocolat aux noisettes” is correct, in a situation with several chocolates.