# I have a doubt regarding french negation

Tags: négation

Can someone please tell me, that in a negative sentence, does 'du' change into anything?

I'm really confused

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uses of “de” and “du” after a negative](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13905/uses-of-de-and-du-after-a-negative)

Answer (score 1):

yes it changes.
For example : 
"J'ai un oncle" (I have an uncle)
it becomes "Je n'ai pas d'oncle" (I have no uncle)

"J'ai du travail à faire" (I have work to do)
"Je n'ai pas de travail à faire" (I have no work to do)

" J'ai de la chance" (I have chance/luck)
"Je n'ai pas de chance" (I have no chance/luck)