# Les articles partitifs (du, de)

Tags: grammaire, de, partitif

I am confused whether **de** is used as it is a negative sentence, but I have seen **du** in the french translator apps.

> nicolas n'aime pas boire _ rhum.

Comment: You should find sufficient explanations [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/13905/17649). If something is not clear or if there is something more you want to ask about, modify your text, and explain what it is.

Comment: yeah it helped. thx