# Gamme de produit, de produits, ou des produits ?

Tags: pluriel

Donc on dit *« la gamme de produit »* , *« la gamme de produits »* ou *« la gamme des produits »* ? Tout est question de **s** s'il vous plait.

La phrase est :

> la présentation de la gamme de produits XXX par la société YYY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On dit la **gamme de produits** si tu veux parler de

> l'ensemble (ou l'un des sous-ensembles) des produits, marques ou références d'une entreprise organisés ou classés suivant certains critères. ([Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamme_de_produits))

Cependant, la *"gamme des produits"* est [toléré](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gamme%20des%20produits%2C%20gamme%20de%20produits&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgamme%20des%20produits%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgamme%20de%20produits%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 5):

> la gamme de produits
>
> la gamme des produits

Sont tous deux valables.  Le premier signifiant "la gamme de des produits" avec contraction de "de des" en "de", le second signifiant "la gamme de les produits" avec contraction de "de les" en "des".  En général, le premier correspond mieux au contexte mais quand *produit* est qualifié comme dans ton exemple, il n'est pas difficile de trouver des contextes où un "des" convient mieux.

Comment: Il me semble que la contraction habituelle pour « de des » est « des ». Je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse d'une contraction, de même que lorsque l'on parle d'un « ensemble d'éléments ».

Comment: @Chop, voir http://french.stackexchange.com/a/7585/176.  Si j'y pense ce soir, je peux retrouver ça dans le Bon Usage.

Comment: Au temps pour moi. Merci.