# Pourquoi "de" au lieu de "des"

Tags: grammaire

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative
>   d'extorsion de fonds **de la part de maîtres-chanteurs présumés**, qui
>   auraient été en possession d'une vidéo intime de Mathieu Valbuena.
>   Depuis le début, il nie toute implication dans un chantage.

Maître-chanteur est un nom masculin (https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/maitre-chanteur)
Par conséquent, pour moi il y a une erreur dans la partie en gras, et il faut plutôt dire: **de la part des (de+les) maîtres-chanteurs présumés**.

Qu'elle est la règle utilisée ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il n'y a pas d'erreur. Il s'agit ici d'une supposition où l'on n'identifie pas dans le texte les maîtres-chanteurs en question.

C'est donc **de** qui est une contraction de **de des**, préposition **de** suivie de l'article indéfini **des**, qui est utilisée.

« De la part **des** maîtres-chanteurs présumés » = « …**de les** maîtres-chanteurs » pourrait être employé si ces derniers étaient identifiés (ils le sont peut-être déjà par la police, mais dans le texte, les maîtres-chanteurs ne sont pas définis).

En remplaçant maître-chanteur par cambrioleur, plus simple à utiliser au féminin :

Article défini masculin (**de le** → **du**) :

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative de vol de la part **du** cambrioleur présumé

Article défini féminin (**de la**, pas de contraction dans ce cas) :

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative de vol de la part **de la** cambrioleuse présumée

Article défini féminin pluriel, **de la** devient **de les** qui se contracte comme au masculin en **des** :

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative de vol de la part **des** cambrioleuses présumées

Article indéfini (**de une** → **d'une**) :

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative de vol de la part **d'une** cambrioleuse présumée

Article indéfini féminin pluriel, **d'une (de une)** devient **de des** qui se contracte comme au masculin en **de** :

> La justice le soupçonne d'avoir joué un rôle dans une tentative de vol de la part **de** cambrioleuses présumées

Voir [le point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/articles_de_du2.htm) et aussi [« Parler de » + un article partitif ou l'article indéfini « des » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/parler-de-un-article-partitif-ou-larticle-ind%C3%A9fini-des)

Comment: ça n'a pas grand chose à voir avec le fait qu'ils soient présumés ou non je pense. "De la part de maîtres-chanteurs" est aussi correct que "de la part de maîtres-chanteurs présumés".

Comment: Les deux phrases sont grammaticalement correctes mais n'ont pas le même sens.

Comment: Oui, effectivement, "des" est moins vague que "de", mais selon le contexte, on peut utiliser "de" à la place de "des" et ce n'est pas toujours aussi clair (voir les exemples de ma réponse) Je me préparais à un pareil coup bas de la part de voleurs aussi rusés = les voleurs sont connus aussi. Si on dit "de la part des voleurs", là on les désigne.

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE Réponse modifiée pour apporter une explication.

Comment: Oui, c'est mieux. Cette réponse est correcte, la mienne était incomplète, mais elle n'était pas fausse. En fait, il faudrait joindre les 2 réponses pour avoir une réponse vraiment complète. Car "de" n'est pas que générique, cela dépend des phrases. de la part de voleurs aussi rusés, ici les voleurs sont bien spécifiés, mais le fait d'ajouter une description force à utiliser le "de".

Comment: @PERCE-NEIGE « Je me préparais à un pareil coup bas de la part des voleurs aussi rusés » est incorrect/impossible. L'article indéfini est obligatoirement utilisé ici car il s'agit ici de «voleurs aussi rusés [qu'eux]», pas directement de ceux-là en particulier.

Comment: L'explication comme quoi "des" = "de les" et "de" ="de des" n'est pour moi pas un argument : ça ne veut rien dire...

Comment: @ThomasGuénet Réponse de nouveau éditée avec plus de détails sur la contraction de la préposition **de** suivie d'un article défini ou indéfini.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a une légère nuance entre les deux versions, les deux sont correctes et dépendent de ce que l'auteur souhaite transmettre comme message :

- « de la part des maîtres-chanteurs » : les maîtres-chanteurs sont connus.
- « de la part de maîtres-chanteurs » : les maîtres-chanteurs n'ont pas tous été identifiés (il en existe peut-être d'autres).

Comment: Oui, comme ça c'est plus clair, c'est vrai que l'emploi de "des" désigne les maîtres-chanteurs comme connus, et la seconde est plus vague.

Comment: La seconde donne un type d'individu, la première définit spécifiquement un groupe d'individus.

Answer (score -3):

Oui, de la part des maîtres-chanteurs est correct.

Mais ici, il est aussi correct de dire "de la part de maîtres-chanteurs", comme "de la part de" est pris comme une expression invariable il me semble.

Par exemple, si je dis les phrases suivantes, toutes sont correctes, mais avec des logiques grammaticales différentes:

- *Je me préparais à un pareil coup bas de la part **de mes** ennemis.*
- *Je me préparais à un pareil coup bas de la part **de** voleurs aussi rusés*.
- *Je me préparais à un pareil coup bas de la part **des** adversaires de cette réforme*.

Dans l'exemple donné dans la question, le journaliste forme sa phrase suivant le modèle du deuxième exemple.