# Quand je dois utiliser 'des' et 'de'

Tags: de

Est-ce que quelqu'un peux m'expliquer la difference entry:

```
Je fais des erreurs.
```

Mais quand j'ajoute 'beaucoup' ca change a d(e)?

```
Je fais beaucoup d'erreurs.
```

Pourquoi la phrase suivante est-elle fausse ?

```
Je fais beaucoup des erreurs. | faux
```

Et c'est pas assez. Mais la phrase suivante est-elle correcte encore.

```
Je fais parfois des erreurs.
```

Merci!

Comment: After writing this I get the feeling 'des' is not just plural of 'de', rather it means 'some', and only 'some'. Does anyone have a mnemonic for me?

Comment: "De" is a preposition, and does not have a plural form. "Des" can be either a contraction of the preposition "de" and the definite plural article "les" (="of the"), or an indefinite plural article (="some").

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I think that answered my question. Feel free to post this as an answer instead so I can give you the credit

Comment: I think there might be some older posts that cover this topic, so first I'm going to spend a bit of time trying to see if there is one that gives a more complete answer

Comment: Maybe the answer here would be helpful: [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869) Also see [Why is it “Ils ont besoin de livres et de DVDs” and not “des livres et des DVDs”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/25571) and [When to use “de” or “des” after nouns and after “beaucoup”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13872)